# I am not able to implement to reply message to twilio number

Tags: node.js, twilio, sms, twilio-twiml, inbound

I need to create 2 way SMS API in nodejs. I am receiving a message from twilio but I am not receiving a message when I reply to the same message

reply.js

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const MessagingResponse = require("twilio").twiml.MessagingResponse;
const app = express();
app.post("/sms", (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  console.log(req.body);
  twiml.message("Thank you for calling!. We got your message, Thank You.");
  res.writeHead(200, { "content-Type": "text/xml" });
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http
  .createServer(app)
  .listen(3000, () => console.log("server is up and running on port 3000"));
```

I updated the url in twilio number in webhook for message come in field from ngrok by ngrok http 3000.
whenever I used to reply the message I am not able to see any log in ngrok.
plase help me.
Is there any restriction for india origin based number. I used to reply messgae from India number.

Comment: `"I updated the url in twilio number in webhook"`. Check that url and make sure it includes `/sms`, not just the ngrok domain.

Answer (score 0):

Check you [debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger?quickDate=72) in the Twilio console, it most likely has an error message. You must send an SMS into Twilio for your TwiML, `Thank you for calling!. We got your message, Thank You.` to apply.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is the first place to look if your configuration is set up properly.
All webhook calls errors and warnings are logged there